# Finding the sum of a list

Tags: python

Just looking for a more efficient approach to adding a very large number in a list together. I know I can use the sum() function, but I'm wondering if there is any other better or efficient approach.

```
nums = list(range(17832931))
ans = sum(nums)
```

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: `sum` is written in C. Its going to be hard to get faster.

Comment: If your list is as predictable as a range object you can do a little math and get a formula like (n^2 - n) / 2. That would work for adding integer from 1 to n

Comment: `np.sum` will be faster for numpy arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just trying to sum the numbers in a range, you can simply use `(n-1)*n//2`. For example:

```
n = 100
print(sum(range(n)))
print((n-1)*n//2)
```

Output

```
4950
4950
```

Comment: [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)

Comment: Thanks guys, think will stick what I have. Great tips all round though :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the solution could be using `Lambda` function. Refer [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-lambda-function-b6e1fa3420c1)

```
final_sum = sum(map(lambda x: x, list(range(26363637))))
print(final_sum)

# Output : 347520664752066
```

In the bove solution, I've used a `lambda function` and mapped each value using [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function and then uses inbuilt function `sum` which will add each iterable and will return the sum

Comment: Please don't just post a solution, but add an explanation as to why the code fulfills the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach :

```
sum = 0 
number_list = list(range(26363637))
for number in number_list:
    sum += number 
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nums = list(range(17832931))
ans = [*map(lambda N:  (N*(N+1))/2, [nums[len(nums)-1]])]
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so everyone has answered. To sum from `1` to `n`, @Nick's answer is the best advise.

But if you just have a iterable and want to sum of it. Just use the `sum` function.

Remember not to convert it to `list` or `tuple`. Just use `sum` in the iterable.

Here's what I mean:

```py
nums = range(17832931)
ans = sum(nums)
```

When you convert the `nums` to a `list`, it takes O(n) time to do that; which is completely unnecessary.
Example:

```py
nums = range(17832931)
ans = sum(nums) # takes O(n) time
     # Total: O(n) 

nums = list(range(17832931)) # takes O(n) time
ans = sum(nums) # takes O(n) time
     # Total: O( 2n )
```

### Conclusion

In python, there's no other function or method to optimize the sum of values.

However, if you can figure out what kind of values you have, then you do it in O(1) complexity by using some math formula. As @Nick used `n(n+1)/2`

Comment: I suggested @Nick's answer in the first line!

In the question and also in some other answers, they converted the `range()` to a `list` first. My answer was to forbid them to do that. Cuz, that way, they are doing a `O(n)` work for nothing. 

So, my advise was, to sum from 1 to n, do as @Nick said.
For other cases, just use `sum` without converting it to a `list`

Comment: Ah, man. I messed up. I posted another question's answer here. Ahhhhhhh

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77043663/18256963