# How can i create a new list of sublist?

Tags: python

SO I am currently trying to do some exercises in python and i don't quite understand how to take a list of strings which is called s and build a new list of sub lists that is called as r.

So if i have an input

```
s = [ 'It is', 'time', 'for', 'tea' ]
```

the output list r should contain:

```
[ [0,'It is'], [1,'time'], [2,'for'], [3,'tea'] ]
```

Can someone please help me understand and get the answer?

I have tried to do this but its not the answer that i want.

```
def sub_lists(list1): 

    # store all the sublists  
    sublist = [[]] 

    # first loop  
    for i in range(len(list1) + 1): 

        # second loop  
        for j in range(i + 1, len(list1) + 1): 

            # slice the subarray  
            sub = list1[i:j] 
            sublist.append(sub) 


    return sublist 

# driver code 
s = [ 'It is', 'time', 'for', 'tea' ]
print(sub_lists(s))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) for this:

```
s = [ 'It is', 'time', 'for', 'tea' ] 
r = [[index, value] for index, value in enumerate(s)]
print(r)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 'It is'], [1, 'time'], [2, 'for'], [3, 'tea']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate()`:

```
s = [ 'It is', 'time', 'for', 'tea' ]
s = [[i,v] for i,v in enumerate(s)] 
print(s)
```

Or, if you're not ready for that, you can use subscriptions:

```
s = [ 'It is', 'time', 'for', 'tea' ]
s = [[i,s[i]] for i in range(len(s))] 
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this has already been answered, I wanted to show the use case of the built in [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function.

```py
s = ['It is', 'time', 'for', 'tea']

r = list(zip(range(len(s)), s))

print(r) # [(0, 'It is'), (1, 'time'), (2, 'for'), (3, 'tea')]
```

`zip` returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument iterables.

`zip()` is lazy. So the elements won’t be processed until the iterable is iterated on, e.g. by a for loop or by wrapping in a list.

Could save up your memory when you will just access the values of it one by one.

But if you just want to make another list/tuple of it, then you might consider the first answer of @Nick.

I also went to do a benchmark of all the three answers here. Here's what I found.

```py
from timeit import timeit


def ans1(): # @Nick
    s = ['It is', 'time', 'for', 'tea']
    r = [[index, value] for index, value in enumerate(s)]


def ans2(): # @Red
    s = ['It is', 'time', 'for', 'tea']
    s = [[i, s[i]] for i in range(len(s))]


def ans3(): # @Nusab19 | Mine
    s = ['It is', 'time', 'for', 'tea']
    r = list(zip(range(len(s)), s))


avg1 = sum(timeit(ans1, number=1000000) for _ in range(10)) / 10
avg2 = sum(timeit(ans2, number=1000000) for _ in range(10)) / 10
avg3 = sum(timeit(ans3, number=1000000) for _ in range(10)) / 10


print(avg1) # 0.5417955400014762
print(avg2) # 0.6422853300027782
print(avg3) # 0.5304447900009108
```

So, mine does speed up the execution by a bit. But sometimes the ans1 comes a bit lower too. So, not much of a difference.

Python Version Used: **3.11.5**